# Docking a StatusStrip control on Bottom and a Panel on Right in an MDI Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have a MDI parent form as the main window of my application. Within this `Form` I also have two other `Control` a `Panel` and a `StatusStrip` which are docked to the `Right` and `Bottom` respectively.

My issue is that the `StatusStrip` does not "fill" the entire bottom of the `Form`. It is stopped by the `Panel` on the right.

[image]

I would have figured by the `DockStyle` graphic in the properties window of Visual Studio that the `Bottom` docked `Control` would fill the entire bottom of the `Form`.

[image]

Is there a way to have the `StatusStrip` fill the entire bottom and have the `Panel` docked to the `Right` while still maintaining the MDI area? (undocked controls in the MDI area allow windows to be "hidden" behind them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order matters when the controls are placed on the form.  To correct that, you can use the [Bring-To-Front](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Send-To-Back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

While in the designer, right mouse-click the StatusStrip control and select the Send-To-Back option, or alternatively, select the panel control, and select the Bring-To-Front option.

Comment: Worked perfectly! First time I think I have ever had to use that menu option. Thanks!